# Could not locate any relevant foreign key columns for primary join condition

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlalchemy

I have 4 sqlalchemy classes:

```
class A(Base):
    id = Column("id", VARCHAR(255), primary_key=True)
```

```
class B(Base):
    id = Column("id", VARCHAR(255), primary_key=True)
```

```
class X(Base):
    a_id = Column("a_id", VARCHAR(255), ForeignKey("A.id"), primary_key=True)
    b_id = Column("b_id", VARCHAR(255), ForeignKey("B.id"), primary_key=True)


    y_mappings = relationship(
        "Y",
        primaryjoin="and_(X.a_id==Y.a_id, X.b_id==Y.b_id)",
    )
```

```
class Y(Base):
    a_id = Column("a_id", VARCHAR(255), ForeignKey("A.id"), primary_key=True)
    b_id = Column("b_id", VARCHAR(255), ForeignKey("B.id"), primary_key=True)
    name = Column("name ", VARCHAR(255), primary_key=True)
```

but I got this error on `X.y_mappings`:

```
Could not locate any relevant foreign key columns for primary join condition ... Ensure that referencing columns are associated with a ForeignKey or ForeignKeyConstraint, or are annotated in the join condition with the foreign() annotation.
```

check the doc: https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/orm/join_conditions.html#specifying-alternate-join-conditions and use `primaryjoin`, but it didn't work.

Comment: The column names for `a_id` and `b_id` have an extra space at the end. This extra space might be causing the issue because SQLAlchemy is not able to find a match for the ForeignKey constraints. Remove those spaces and try again

Comment: thanks for the comment, I edited the code, but that's not the root cause. I add `foreign_keys` in relationships and the error disappeared, but the relationship didn't work as other relationships, it's a 1-1 mapping(what I want is a 1 to many relationship)